# Binding to an array in ember with @each

Tags: ember.js

I was reading about how to observe an array and do something when elements were added or removed. [See the official explanation here](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/). The page says that if we observe with `anArray.@each` then it should fire in the case of adding an object to the array.

I tested that [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hobarenu/1/edit) and had two problems:

1. The observer I put on the component did not fire.
2. The dom did not update its displaying of the length of the array.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `pushObject` when adding items to an array in Ember, it's how Ember is able to keep track of whether or not the array has changed.  Likewise you need to always use `get`/`set` on your objects, also Ember's way of knowing that a property has changed on an object.

```
this.get('testArray').pushObject('foo');
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hobarenu/2/edit

Comment: Thanks, this is the  sort of thing it's easy to forget sometime in Ember. I am super familiaar with why using 'set' is important for triggering observers, I should have figured there would be something similar for modifying arrays.